# 'strategic tactical way' vs. 'strategic tactic'

Tags: adjectives

> 'It's not a 'mistake', but a *strategic tactical way* to make sure ...'

Is it proper English *strategic tactical way* or would it be more idiomatic to say *strategic tactic*?

Comment: I'm not sure that the words "strategic" and "tactical" combine as adjectives. They are to a certain extent antonymous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tactical is correct. It is Strategic that is possibly incorrect.  You could say...

> It's not a 'mistake', but a strategic, tactical way to make sure ...'

Using a comma after strategic tells the reader that strategic describes "way."  So it is a strategic way and a tactical way.

Or you can say...

> It's not a 'mistake', but a strategically tactical way to make sure ...'

In this sentence, strategically describes "tactical way."  Personally, I think this second sentence reads smoother to the native English speaker's ear. Hope this helps!